# On the division of each array by its norm in Python

Tags: python, matlab, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix `H` of size `4 x 4`, and a vector y of size `4 x 1`, I need to get the results of `(h'/norm(h, 'fro')) * y` in Python, where `h` is the columns of matrix `H` and `h`' is the transpose of every column of matrix `H`. For example in MATLAB I did it straightforwardly as below:

```matlab
clear all 
clc 

H = [0.0937 + 1.5453i,  -0.1910 - 0.3741i,   1.4420 + 0.6273i,   0.0518 - 0.4653i; ...
    0.8537 + 0.9905i,  -0.2910 + 0.0131i,   0.2993 - 0.5929i,   0.6426 + 0.4098i;...
    0.3722 - 0.3470i,   0.0449 - 0.2985i,  -0.7595 - 0.1346i,  -1.2782 + 0.1877i; ...
    -0.8256 + 0.5255i,  -0.5318 - 0.0624i,  -0.5467 - 0.4118i,   0.0772 + 0.9888i]; 
y = [0.1037 + 0.1302i; 0.3676 - 0.0198i; 0.2380 + 0.2824i; 0.0557 - 0.4222i];
re = []; 
for ii = 1 : size(H,2)
    nn = H(:,ii);
    tt = (nn'/norm(nn,'fro') * y)
    re = [re tt]
end
```

But in Python it gives an error! I gave a try as below:

```
import numpy as np

h = np.array([[0.0937 + 1.5453j,  -0.1910 - 0.3741j,   1.4420 + 0.6273j,   0.0518 - 0.4653j],
   [0.8537 + 0.9905j,  -0.2910 + 0.0131j,  0.2993 - 0.5929j,   0.6426 + 0.4098j],
  [0.3722 - 0.3470j,   0.0449 - 0.2985j,  -0.7595 - 0.1346j,  -1.2782 + 0.1877j],
  [-0.8256 + 0.5255j,  -0.5318 - 0.0624j,  -0.5467 - 0.4118j,   0.0772 + 0.9888j]])

y = np.array([[0.1037 + 0.1302j], [0.3676 - 0.0198j], [0.2380 + 0.2824j], [0.0557 - 0.4222j]])

n = 3
re= np.zeros((1, 4), dtype=np.complex)
for ii in range(n):
    re[:, ii] = ((np.linalg.pinv(h[:, ii])).transpose() / (np.linalg.norm(np.linalg.pinv(h[:, ii]), 'fro'))).dot(y)
```

But I get an error when running the last command of `re[:, ii] = ((np.linalg.pinv(h[:, ii])).transpose() / (np.linalg.norm(np.linalg.pinv(h[:, ii]), 'fro'))).dot(y)`, it says:

> numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: 1-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional

Comment: What error do you get and in what line?

Comment: @Nils it's modified in the question

Comment: Well `np.linalg.pinv()` calculates the inverse of a Matrix, but you hand it a one dimensional array, just like the error suggests, but it takes only 2-d arrays.

Comment: I don't know matlab, so what is `norm(nn, 'fro')` doing? I am guessing it will calculate a norm, but what is `'fro'`?

Comment: @Nils, "The Frobenius-norm of matrix `A`, `sqrt(sum(diag(A'*A)))`." according to the docs.

Comment: So why do you calculate the inverse of the matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I executed your Matlab™ code to get these values for `re` :

```
[0.098760-0.009564i, -0.316010+0.408531i, 0.139199+0.203590i, -0.264498-0.323802i]
```

This Python/Numpy code

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
H = np.array(([ 0.0937 + 1.5453j,  -0.1910 - 0.3741j,   1.4420 + 0.6273j,   0.0518 - 0.4653j], 
              [ 0.8537 + 0.9905j,  -0.2910 + 0.0131j,   0.2993 - 0.5929j,   0.6426 + 0.4098j], 
              [ 0.3722 - 0.3470j,   0.0449 - 0.2985j,  -0.7595 - 0.1346j,  -1.2782 + 0.1877j], 
              [-0.8256 + 0.5255j,  -0.5318 - 0.0624j,  -0.5467 - 0.4118j,   0.0772 + 0.9888j]))                         

y = np.array([0.1037 + 0.1302j, 0.3676 - 0.0198j, 0.2380 + 0.2824j, 0.0557 - 0.4222j])                                  

np.conjugate(H/norm(H, axis=0)).T@y
```

gives

```
array([ 0.09875966-0.00956369j, -0.31600998+0.40853066j,  0.13919918+0.20358966j, -0.26449838-0.32380165j])
```

I think that the main issue here is that transposing a complex array in Matlab™ gives you the transpose conjugate, transposing the same array in Numpy does not perform the conjugation.  Another issue is that a mat-vec dot product (the `@` operator) is row-column, while you need col-col, so we need a transposition too.

Comment: thank you so much, you mean this command : np.conjugate(h/np.linalg.norm(h, axis=0)).T@y    ? is that right? .. but in this case you are calculating the norm of h,  but not norm frobenius. however, they are not similar

Comment: Frobenius norm applies to 2D matrices, here you are applying it to a single column of a matrix and it's hence indistinguishable from an ordinary SRSS norm.  Further, when computing the norm of a 2D matrix Numpy  by default  uses the Frobenius norm, but this is not the case here because we used the `axis` keyword argument. Eventually, my result matches the result of Mᴀᴛʟᴀʙ™. — It is sad that you won't recognize the correctness of my answer but I will survive.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will do what you want:

Also in your code `n` should be equal to 4:

```
n = 4
for ii in range(n):
    tmp1 = (h[:, ii]).transpose()
    tmp2 = (np.linalg.norm(h[:, ii].transpose()))
    re[:, ii] = (tmp1 / tmp2).dot(y)
```

Please see if it will achieve the same results as in matlab. I fixed your errors, but I am not sure if that is the correct calculation.

I also deleted the `fro` from calculating the norm as `linalg.norm()` is using it by default and specifically adding it causes some trouble. For more details see here:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html

Comment: It doesn't give the same results unfortunately. Here's [MATLAB](https://tio.run/##TZDNboMwEITvPMXekrTE3V3/B/Wed6h6iCiRLFGQKKqUvjxdbFB7QWY8/mZ2x3a@fXfL0vbdbYJb30PV9i1U1RVe4Q0VRu3hGUhZY3WqAc6oKBLCGVBpb2jV5NoYRvGhcuyzT45oKWSfcfK2AaVUBfkm2ExFFSPajcorddWQNG0EjlFngo0cN80ZdtlnMIbU/EG1Zy61jMe9gjExaxzDHuRttFkjbVzWSLEPnKEUvP9XVeyBbcmzbHeE1dtk6NjsmnG@TEsU9njvCzaGENJ7A9WjrJVwWwBpZMmT0s67gqR1rLWyDmUhHCSkyQu1WwQzC66auhW3cu/jBCnJH8EFvtJPd7zWfMozDIPI1@OlTunUZGWeRTkOw@FlGKdPOdSH@zQeTvAEj81SyPKd5/eidMMHSOCy/AI), and you may paste your Python code [here](https://tio.run/#python2).

Comment: Yea I just noticed :/ My guess is that the norm function calculates it differently. Nope, in fact do both norms return the same result.

Comment: Interestingly does `tmp1/tmp2` return the same result as `nn'/norm(nn,'fro')`. So something has to be up with the dot product.